# AngularJS how to bind data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've this *HTML* markup using *Bootstrap*:

```
<div class="col-sm-6" ng-app ng-controller="MyController">   
    <br/><br/>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="input" class="form-control" ng-model="input" ng-maxlength="18" ng-minlength="18" placeholder="Type input.." aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2" ng-bind="inputMaxLength"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this *AngularJS* controller:

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.input = "";
    $scope.inputMaxLength = 18;
}
```

What is the recommended solution for implementing the "charaters left" feature in the *bootstrap addon*? Further, how can I change the input field so that I cannot type in more then 18 charaters?

See this demo example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/7ugzn76s/2/

**UPDATE 1**

I've updated the JSFiddle, based on your answers. But the countdown does not work:
http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/7ugzn76s/3/

Comment: `how can I change the input field so that I cannot type in more then 18 charaters`. This is simple: `<input maxlength="18">`.

Comment: To show "characters left" you could simply do: `{{inputMaxLength - input.length}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve your result. I've seen that you've updated the fiddle but you're still having problems with the "remaining chars" numbers. you have to bind a the result of the remaining chars calculus.

```
<div class="col-sm-6" ng-app ng-controller="MyController">   
<br/><br/>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="input" class="form-control" ng-model="myInput" maxlength="18" minlength="18" placeholder="Type input.." aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">{{inputMaxLength - myInput.length}}</span>
</div>
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5kvjdov/1/

Answer (score 1):

As forked from your update 1: http://jsfiddle.net/5ka355sa/

Two changes 
1. `ng-bind` is always an expression, don't use curly braces there.
2. You used `ng-minlength = "18"` which mean things like 'foo' were invalid as they were too short. Invalid values aren't added to the model.

```
<input type="text" name="input" class="form-control" ng-model="input" maxlength="{{inputMaxLength}}" ng-maxlength="{{inputMaxLength}}" placeholder="Type input.." aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2" ng-bind="inputMaxLength - input.length"></span>`\
```

Alternatively for the label you can do

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">{{inputMaxLength - input.length}} characters left.</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the value out of ng-bind and put between span:

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2" >{{inputMaxLength-input.length}}</span>
```

And now it is performing as expected, also on the ng-maxlenght use only the var name and not the moustache {{}}

You can see in the next jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yuzdL4c3/1/